# Does an IIS worker process clear session variables when it recycles?

Tags: iis, session-variables, worker-process

We're writing an asp.net web app on IIS 6 and are planning on storing our user login variables in a session. Will this be removed when the worker process recycles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If session is stored in-proc then YES worker process recycle will remove it. Use Out-of-proc model or sql server to store session value if you want to keep it stored.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **default in-memory session management**, the session variables will be **cleared** when worker process recycles

Answer (score 0):

yes, unless you are using out of process session state.